# calculus question proving function equals constant

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=f(x+1)$ and $limf(x)=2 $ as $x\rightarrow \infty $, then $f(x)=2$.

I know by the definitions that: To every $\epsilon>0 $ exists $x>M$ that follows $|f(x)-2|=|f(x+1)-2|<\epsilon$.

I guess I nees to get some contradiction... but I don't see it. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, the definition is: for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $M>0$ such that whenever $x>M$ then $|f(x)-2| < \epsilon$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566219/the-difference-between-two-periodic-functions-converges-to-zero-is-this-two-fun).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $f$ is not constant, and choose $x_0$ with $f(x_0) \ne 2$. Set $\epsilon = \frac{|f(x_0)-2|}{2}$. Can you get a contradiction?